# How to convert BEGIN_OBJECT to BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, android

i'm beginner of java, and i need some help, I had see many posts about, but not work they issues

I had json object from url like that

```
{
    'history':[{
            'id':2,
             'name':'irine'},
          {
            'id':3,
             'name':'karine'
             }]
}
```

but i need

```
[
           {
           'id':2,
             'name':'irine'},
          {
            'id':3,
             'name':'karine'}
]
```

my ApiClient.java

public class ApiClient {

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.150.100";
public static Retrofit retrofit;


public static Retrofit getApiClient(final String authToken){

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                    ongoing.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;");
                    ongoing.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);

                        return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
                }
            })//.addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
    if (retrofit==null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

getting response from url

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                contacts=response.body();

                if(contacts==null)
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.lt_search), "Nothing found",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter = new Adapter(contacts, SearchActivity.this);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("GHaa ka sk aksjdk j", contacts.toString());
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

how to convert object to array or clear word 'history' from object?

Comment: please provide at least sample input and output and your code, preferably as a minimal working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided the wrong class for API response.You are getting the `list` object against a `string key` which might change(not known). So, you will have to use `HashMap`. The API response is in the form of `HashMap<String,<List<Contact>>>`. So in the code, you will have to use `Callback<HashMap<String,List<Contact>>>()` instead of `Callback<List<Contact>>()`.

Then from the `HashMap` you can easily get the `list` using `hashmap.get('key')`. In your case, `hashmap.get('history')`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to reselve this problem:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<HashMap<String,List<Contact>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HashMap<String, List<Contact>>> call, Response<HashMap<String, List<Contact>>> response) {
                HashMap<String, List<Contact>> history=response.body();
                contacts= new ArrayList<>(history.get("hitory"));
                Log.d(TAG, contacts.toString());

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //contacts=response.toString();
                Log.d(TAG,response.toString());
                if(contacts==null)
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.lt_search), "Nothing found",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter = new Adapter(contacts, SearchActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HashMap<String, List<Contact>>> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //Log.d("GHaa ka sk aksjdk j", contacts.toString());
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
```